# ¿Cómo adicionar la parte de un path a la opción file.write()?

Tags: python

Hola estoy haciendo una pruebas con python y quisiera saber si me podian ayudar en algo. 
Tengo el siguiente path: /media/documents/archivo20100208.fits

lo que ocurre es que deseo escribir la parte "archivo20100208" del path en un archivo .txt.con la opción file.write().

¿Alguna idea de como puedo cortar esa parte del path y colocarlo en la opción write?

Deseo que la fecha me quede con su formato debido, para archivo20180208 quiero que me quede solamente 2010 - 02 - 08

Mi código fuente es:

```
path = '/media/documents/archivo20100208.fits'
file = open("/media/documents/Archivo_fecha.txt","a")
file.write()
file.close()
```

Comment: Hola, puedes usar expresiones regulares (regex) para extraer patrones de un string. Si piensas hacerlo para varios archivos con longitud variable y tienen un formato establecido, sería la mejor opción. Si solo lo vas a hacer para uno o pocos, y tienen longitud fija puedes indexar la parte que necesitas o separar (split) por caracteres, por ejemplo separas por `/` y luego por `.`. Si aclaras esto en tu pregunta podría crear una respuesta más apropiada.

Comment: @gustavovelascoh la parte archivo20100208 es la que deseo cortar del path y colocarlo en la filewrite(), si es para varios archivos, un aproximado de 300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opcion es usar el metodo split() de python, la cual separa un string dado un caracter que se usa de separador. Puedes separar el path dado el caracter "/", lo que devolvera lo siguiente

```
    path = '/media/documents/archivo20100208.fits'
    list_of_word = path.split('/')
    print(list_of_word)
    #['', 'media', 'documents', 'archivo20100208.fits']
```

Luego puedes volver a aplicar la funcion split pero ahora sobre "."

```
    date = list_of_word.split[-1](".")
    print(date)
    #['archivo20100208', 'fits']
```

Ahora si juntamos ambas expresiones, y como sabemos que la fecha esta al final de la primera lista y que lo que se encuentre después del punto no sirve puedes dejarlo en una sola linea de la siguiente manera:

```
    date = path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    print(date)
    #archivo20100208
```

Comment: en date=list_of_words.split('.') Se te olvidó iindice -1, es decir, debería ser list_of_words[-1].split('.')

Comment: toda la razon, editado, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con el uso de expresiones regulares puedes extraer la parte del nombre de archivo que te interesa. Por ejemplo:

```
import re

paths = ["/media/documents/archivo20100208.fits",
         "/media/documents/archivo20100209.fits",
         "/media/documents/archivo20100301.fits",
         "/media/documents/archivo20100402.fits"]

regex_str = "^.*(?P<fecha>archivo[0-9]{8}).fits$"
r = re.compile(regex_str)

for p in paths:
    result = r.search(p)

    if result:
        fecha = result.group("fecha") 
        print(fecha)
        # fecha = archivo20100208
        # Escribir fecha
```